# Is there a second success in angular $q.all() as in jQuery $.get()

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

Looking at the jQuery documentation I found out the following:

```
$.get( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" ); <---
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

I need to execute a method in Angular controller after making few ajax calls, like following:

```
 $q.all([
            $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetStates"),
            $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetCountries"),
            $http.get(ROOT + "Address/GetAddresses"),
        ]).then(function (results) {
            $scope.states = jQuery.parseJSON(results[0].data.data);
            $scope.country = jQuery.parseJSON(results[1].data.data);
            $scope.addresses = jQuery.parseJSON(results[3].data);
        });
```

after the `then` gets executed **(only after the then)** I need to call a method `$scope.setupControls()`

Is there a possibility for this?

Comment: why are you using `parseJSON()`?

Comment: @charlietfl to be frank I am not sure. I am sending a JsonResult this is not needed?

Comment: no it shouldn't be if sending properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
.finally(function() {
  // do this on both error and success
});
```

As it says, executes after success and error

So Full code:

```
$q.all([
        $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetStates"),
        $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetCountries"),
        $http.get(ROOT + "Address/GetAddresses"),
    ]).then(function (results) {
        $scope.states = jQuery.parseJSON(results[0].data.data);
        $scope.country = jQuery.parseJSON(results[1].data.data);
        $scope.addresses = jQuery.parseJSON(results[3].data);
    }).finally(function() { /* <-- here */
      // do this on both error and success
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Why couldn't you do that :

```
   $q.all([
        $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetStates"),
        $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetCountries"),
        $http.get(ROOT + "Address/GetAddresses"),
    ]).then(function (results) {
        $scope.states = jQuery.parseJSON(results[0].data.data);
        $scope.country = jQuery.parseJSON(results[1].data.data);
        $scope.addresses = jQuery.parseJSON(results[2].data);
        $scope.setupControls();
    });
```

I think there is no need for a second success. Keep It Simple (and Sexy?)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to invoke then multiple times.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
>
> **Chaining promises**
> Because calling the then method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises:

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
   return result + 1;
});

// promiseB will be resolved immediately after promiseA is resolved and its value
// will be the result of promiseA incremented by 1


$q.all([
        $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetStates"),
        $http.get(ROOT + "Lookup/GetCountries"),
        $http.get(ROOT + "Address/GetAddresses"),
    ]).then(function (results) {
        $scope.states = jQuery.parseJSON(results[0].data.data);
        $scope.country = jQuery.parseJSON(results[1].data.data);
        $scope.addresses = jQuery.parseJSON(results[3].data);
    }).then(function (result) {
         //do something here
    }) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular's $q provide the same methods as jQuery's. Details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

One approach I could think of is the following:

```
$http.get('parent request')
.then(function(win){
      // do something when everything is resolved
   },
   function(err){
      //handle error
   },
   function(progress){
      //do something when a child request is resolved
   }
);
```

... where the "parent request" makes some child requests & for each child resolved request you can use `.notfiy()` method to update the parent request & also you should keep track of all your child request status and when all are resolved you can call `.resolve()` and do whatever you want (`$scope.setupControls()` in your case).